# JasperReports: Struts plugin pass a Map as a Parameter

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

This is my first question here!

I am trying to pass a Map as parameter from a struts action to a report. I have inserted the map in the reportParameters map that are being passed to the *jrxml* file.

My question is whether this Map can be retrieved inside the *jrxml* file.

To be More precise, I declare it like this:

```xml
<parameter name="reportParams.testMap" class="java.util.Map"/>
```

and I want to use it like this:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement style="StyleData" x="240" y="0" width="100" height="23"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[testMap.get("AR")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Is it possible? Because I keep getting this error in my application server logs:

```
No such property: testMap for class: Blank32A4_1336385977531_38171
Error evaluating expression : Source text : testMap.get("AR")
Error evaluating expression : Source text : testMap.get("AR")
```

My action class looks like this:

```java
@Injectable
@Results({
@Result(name = "success", type = "jasper", params={"location",
    "report.jasper",
    "connection", "statsConnection",
    "dataSource", "translations",
    "reportParameters","reportParams",
    "format","PDF"})
})
public class LocalMapStatisticNewAction extends ActionSupport{

    ...

    public String execute() {
            reportParams = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
            testMap = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            testMap.put("AR", "Argentina");
            testMap.put("ES", "Spain");
            reportParams.put("testMap", testMap);

            //Jasper code here
    }

    ...

    public Map<String, Object> getReportParams() {
        return reportParams;
    }
}
```

Any hint would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be as simple as you referencing a parameter by the wrong name.

```
testMap.get("AR")
```

You don't have a parameter called `testMap`. You have a parameter called `reportParams.testMap`. Also, you need to refer to parameters like this:

```
$P{testMap}.get("AR")
```

Rename the parameter or rename the reference to the parameter, and you should be OK.